# TSQL how to concatenate horizontally inside the join,

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this task to display CodeName like in sample, and there could be multiple Code separated by commas, I tried to use xml parse but looks like this a bit different situation. In sample code below I did it in simple way but maybe there is better way which be more flexible:
 I also include desired output in photo.
[image: Sample of desired output click here]

```
WITH cte1 AS (
SELECT 'Alpha' Name,  'AA' Code  UNION
SELECT 'Bravo' Name,  'AA,BB,CC' Code  UNION
SELECT 'Whiskey' Name,  NULL Code),
 cteLookup AS (
SELECT 'AA' CodeID,  'Avia' CodeName  UNION
SELECT 'BB' CodeID,  'Bahamas' CodeName  UNION
SELECT 'CC' CodeID,  'Chile' CodeName  )


SELECT Name,
       Code,
       SUBSTRING(Code,1,2) c1,
       x1.CodeName + ', ' +  ISNULL(x2.CodeName,'') + ', ' +   ISNULL(x3.CodeName,'')  
FROM Cte1 
LEFT JOIN cteLookup x1  ON x1.CodeID =  SUBSTRING(Code,1,2)
LEFT JOIN cteLookup x2  ON x2.CodeID =  SUBSTRING(Code,4,2)
LEFT JOIN cteLookup x3  ON x3.CodeID =  SUBSTRING(Code,7,2)
```

Comment: Could you add as text instead of photo ?Images will be blocked in some domains

Comment: I have no idea why you added this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/H1k2W.jpg so have rolled it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH cte1 AS (
SELECT 'Alpha' Name,  'AA' Code  UNION
SELECT 'Bravo' Name,  'AA,BB,CC' Code  UNION
SELECT 'Whiskey' Name,  NULL Code),
 cteLookup AS (
SELECT 'AA' CodeID,  'Avia' CodeName  UNION
SELECT 'BB' CodeID,  'Bahamas' CodeName  UNION
SELECT 'CC' CodeID,  'Chile' CodeName  )

--

SELECT
     A.Name,
     A.Code,
     LEFT(A.CodeName, LEN(A.CodeName) - 1) AS CodeName
FROM
(
    SELECT
        C.Name,
        C.Code,
        (       
            SELECT 
                CL.CodeName + ', ' 
            FROM                
                cteLookup CL
            WHERE 
                C.Code LIKE '%' + CL.CodeID + '%'
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ) AS CodeName

    FROM
        Cte1 C
) A
```

Output

```
Name    Code     CodeName
------- -------- -------------------------
Alpha   AA       Avia
Bravo   AA,BB,CC Avia, Bahamas, Chile
Whiskey NULL     NULL
```